# Why do scripts take significantly longer to run on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a very basic script which downloads a file from S3 and reads a fixed-width .txt file from S3 into a pandas dataframe. The .txt file file is 110.5 MB. However, when I try to execute this same script using AWS Lambda, it times out after 15 minutes.

This comes to me as a surprise because I can load this exact file into a pandas dataframe from my PC in around 10 seconds.

I confirmed the following:

1. There is nothing wrong with the script itself because I am able to successfully execute it via AWS Lambda when I load only a portion of the file (using the nrows parameter), although it still takes a seemingly inordinate amount of time (about 60 seconds per 1000 records-around 1400 KB).
2. The part of the script leading to the timeout is loading the file into the pandas dataframe, as downloading the file from S3 only takes a couple of ms.
3. The increased runtime is not due to memory limitations as the max memory (taken from the execution logs) has never come close to the memory allocated in the General configuration. Additionally, tripling the memory in the General configuration had only an incremental impact on overall runtime (going from about 1 minute per 1000 records to 54 seconds per 1000 records).

Is there a reason why the runtime is significantly greater when running a nearly identical script in AWS Lambda?

```py
import boto3
import logging
import os
import pandas as pd
import tempfile


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3client = boto3.client("s3")


def get_object_name(key):
    object_name = key.split("/")[-1]
    return object_name


def create_directory(object_name):
    temp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    path = os.path.join(temp, object_name)
    return path


def first_name_substring(x):
    first_name_split = x.split(None, 1)
    try:
        if len(first_name_split[1]) > 1 or len(first_name_split[1]) == "[]":
            return x
        else:
            return first_name_split[0]
    except IndexError:
        return x


def read_file(filepath_or_buffer):
    return pd.read_fwf(
            filepath_or_buffer=filepath_or_buffer,
            widths=[8, 9, 1, 2],
            header=None,
            usecols=None,
            names=["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"],
            dtype="category",
            converters={"Column1": "first_name_substring"},
            skiprows=0,
            skipfooter=0,
            na_values=["~", "!","$cdm","- none -","- None -", "-None-", "-none-", "NULL", "null","(NULL)", "(null)","n/a", "N/A", ""],
            keep_default_na=False,
            quotechar='"', 
            doublequote=False,
            encoding="utf-8",
        )


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event["bucket"]
    key = event["key"]

    object_name = get_object_name(key=key)

    read_csv_path = create_directory(object_name=object_name)

    s3.meta.client.download_file(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Filename=read_csv_path)

    pd_dataframe = read_file(filepath_or_buffer=read_csv_path)
```

Comment: How much ram did you allocate for your function?

Comment: Can you confirm that the file is successfully downloaded from S3? Often, a timeout indicates a lack of network connectivity -- just want to rule this out.

Comment: @Marcin, according to the logs, the max memory used by the Lambda function was 837MB. I allocated 2000 MB via the General configuration settings. However, even when I allocated up to 6000 MB, it did not seem to have a significant effect on runtime.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes, I believe it was downloaded successfully because I am able to run the function (i.e., load the file to a pandas dataframe, modify it, and upload it again in S3) if I use nrows to reduce the size of the file.

Comment: You are comparing the execution time to what? Ec2 instance, ECS container?

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproducible example or some code please? Read:https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Marcin, I am comparing it to loading the same .txt file via the read_file function (above) from a folder on my PC. I recognize that this is far from a perfect comparison (e.g. I am not downloading the file from S3) and thus anticipated some differences in the runtime. However, going from 10 seconds to well over 15 minutes (Lambda times out at that point, but tests with portions of the file suggest the function would have to run for over an hour) seems inappropriate.